# NumPy - generate multiple intervals

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array like this:

```
[[0.13, 0.19],
[0.25, 0.6 ],
[0.7 , 0.89]]
```

I want, given the above array, to create a result like this:

```
[[0, 0.12],
[0.13, 0.19],
[0.20, 0.24],
[0.25, 0.60],
[0.61, 0.69],
[0.70, 0.89],
[0.90, 1]]
```

Namely, I want to create a total matrix of intervals, given a pre-defined intervals.

Comment: What have you attempted?  It doesn't have to be "vectorize" but it does need to be clear and reproducible.  We shouldn't have to deduce a pattern.

Comment: I don't have an idea how to create this intervals. That's why I'm asking here :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't specific to numpy, but maybe it will point you in the correct direction.

Basically, you need to know where to start, end, and the 'resolution' (for lack of a better word) — how far apart the gaps are. With that you can loop through the existing intervals and fill in the others. You'll want to watch the edge cases where the intervals are already filled in — like one starting a `0` or `[0.6, 0.8], [0.9, 0.95]` so you don't fill those in twice. This might look something like:

```
def fill_intervals(existing_intervals, start=0, end=1.0, inc=0.01):
    l2 = []
    for i in l:
        if start < i[0]: 
            l2.append([start, i[0] - inc])
        l2.append(i)
        start = i[1] + inc
    if start < end:
        l2.append([start, end])   
        
    return l2

l = [
    [0.13, 0.19],
    [0.25, 0.6 ],
    [0.7 , 0.89]
]

fill_intervals(l)
```

Returning:

```
[[0, 0.12],
 [0.13, 0.19],
 [0.2, 0.24],
 [0.25, 0.6],
 [0.61, 0.69],
 [0.7, 0.89],
 [0.9, 1.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can duplicate items and then make it quite close:

```
arr = np.array([[0.13, 0.19], [0.25, 0.6 ], [0.7 , 0.89]])
consecutive = np.r_[0, np.repeat(arr, 2), 1]
intervals = consecutive.reshape(-1, 2)
```

`intervals`:

```
array([[0.  , 0.13], # required: [0, 0.12]
       [0.13, 0.19], # OK
       [0.19, 0.25], # required: [0.20, 0.24]
       [0.25, 0.6 ], # OK
       [0.6 , 0.7 ], # required: [0.61, 0.69]
       [0.7 , 0.89], # OK
       [0.89, 1.  ]])# required: [0.9, 1]
```

It seems you need to fix alternate intervals so just do:

```
intervals[2::2,0] = intervals[2::2,0] + 0.01
intervals[:-1:2,1] = intervals[:-1:2,1] - 0.01
```

`intervals`:

```
array([[0.  , 0.12],
       [0.13, 0.19],
       [0.2 , 0.24],
       [0.25, 0.6 ],
       [0.61, 0.69],
       [0.7 , 0.89],
       [0.9 , 1.  ]])
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use linspace to create your intervals

```py
import numpy as np 
>>> np.linspace(0, 1, num=3, endpoint=False)
array([0.        , 0.33333333, 0.66666667])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for